# Sumo Simulation and poisson on arrival algorithem

Tags: ns-3, sumo

I am have a project with sumo simulation, i need to use poisson on arrival algorithm in sumo, should i edit the randomTrip file ? or there is another way by using NS-3 ? please help

Comment: Please be a little bit more specific. Which variable do you need to be poisson distributed? If it is the arrival time gaps, this is rather a result of the simulation and hard to be forced on.

Comment: the problem is not in which variable i need to poisson distribute, my problem is how to merge the algorithm in sumo, what i need to distribute is set of nodes(cars) that arrives in exponential quantities

Comment: Can you please give a pointer to the algorithm in question and what you already tried to implement it?